# How to store data between postBack in asp mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback

I have a master page in asp.mvc application. On this master page I have one hidden field which value should be saved between the postback. How Can I achieve it?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How Can I achieve it?

This will depend on how you are performing those postbacks. One possibility would be to simply include it inside the form that you are posting. Another possibility is to use javascript and subscribe for the .submit event of your form and inside read the value of the hidden field and for example append it inside another hidden field to the current form or to the query string so that its value is sent to the server. There might also be other solutions. All will depend on your specific scenario and requirements.

Comment: Technically I use a java script on the master page, and I need to save one value used by IQuery beetwen the postbacks. Master page include a menu with links for another sub-pages which use this master page, and I want to have possibility to keep this value, not matter which link was clicked by user.

Comment: @user927524, why not store this value in a cookie in this case? This way it will automatically be sent on each request.

Comment: @user927524, if my answer helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.